# Operador de Asignaciòn += en Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, dom, li

se que += es un operador de asignación. Más sin embargo, no entiendo que esta haciendo en en el siguiente código que vi en una clase.

```
const dias=["lunes","martes","miercoles"]
for(const days of dias){ul.innerHTML=`<li>${days}</li>`}
```

Se que el for esta dando las vueltas por cada elemento del array de días, y se que el ul junto al inner esta agregando un li a el doc html, y tendra como contenido al miércoles debido que el for esta suscribiendo a cada elemento del array hasta el ultimo. Mas sin embargo al colocar un + en el código como en lo siguiente:

```
const dias=["lunes","martes","miercoles"]
for(const days of dias){ul.innerHTML+=`<li>${days}</li>`}
```

entonces aparecen tantos li como elementos del array tenga es decir:
.Lunes
.Martes
.Miercoles

Mi duda es por que pasa esto realmente porque se agregan con el + y sin el no?
Gracias por responder saludos!

Comment: Tal vez [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) te podría orientar. Saludos

Comment: El colocar `+=` es lo mismo que poner `ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML +  '<li>${days}</li>' `, es decir estás concatenando el contenido que ya existe en el `ul` con el nuevo contenido que quieres añadir.

Answer (score 1):

El operador `+=` no es solo un operador de asignación. Es el operador de asignación `=` junto con el operador `+`. Entra dentro de lo que se conoce como *azúcar sintáctico* o en inglés *syntactic sugar*, es decir, una forma simple o reducida de escribir algo más complejo. En este caso, el código `variable += expresion` vendría a ser lo mismo que escribir `variable = variable + expresion`.

En el fragmento del código que mencionas `ul.innerHTML += '<li>${days}</li>'` al ser el contenido de la variable y la expresion cadenas de texto, lo que está ocurriendo es que el operador `+` concatena las dos cadenas de texto. El resultado final es que en `ul.innerHtml` se van concatenando todos los días del array, cosa que no ocurre si solamente utilizas el operador `=`